# Internal Server Error M2

Tags: magento2

I got this error when trying to deploy my site on server:

> Internal Server Error : The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at 196.203.63.32 Port 80
I am working with magento 2.2.6.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried enabling the error reporting, deploying static contents and updating permissions?

Answer (score 1):

There might many reasons a few of which may be

1. Inappropriate file permission- To apply right permission use

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

2. There may be some errors which can be tracked if you enable error reporting by renaming local.xml.sample to local.xml inside pub/errors folder (obviously in developer mode)
3. static contents not deployed. Use

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: but checked the permissions and upgrade and deploy static nothing  special

Comment: but where to find this local.xml.sample

Comment: I already have mentioned it in my answer, its inside pub/errors folder. Thanks

Comment: Please accept this as answer if it helped you. Thanks